32-point DFT computation of a sampled sinusoidal signal
I encountered this problem: The continuous signal $x(t)=\cos{\Big(\dfrac{2\pi}{16}t+\dfrac{\pi}{6}\Big)}$ is sampled uniformly with a sampling frequency$f_s=2\ Hz$, starting at $t=0$, producing the sequence $x[k]$, where $x[0]=x(0)$. Compute the 32 points DFT for the finite length sequence $s[k]$ defined by $s[k]=x[k]$, $0\leq k < 32$.
What I tried:
After I sample the continuous function, I am left with $x[k]=\cos{\Big(\dfrac{\pi}{4}k + \dfrac{\pi}{6}\Big)}$. I thought of two ways to solve it. One of the methods is based on Euler's formula that states: $$cos(\theta)=\dfrac{e^{j\theta}+e^{-j\theta}}{2}$$and then I try to solve the DFT sum using exponentials alone, like this: $$\begin{alignat}{2}S[n]& =\dfrac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{31}e^{j\frac{\pi}{6}}\ e^{jk\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{-jk\frac{2\pi}{32}n}+e^{-j\frac{\pi}{6}}e^{-jk\frac{\pi}{4}}e^{-jk\frac{2\pi}{32}n} &&\\[2ex] & =\dfrac{1}{2}e^{j\frac{\pi}{6}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{31}e^{jk\frac{\pi}{4}-jk\frac{\pi}{16}n}+\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{6}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{31}e^{-jk\frac{\pi}{4}-jk\frac{\pi}{16}n}&&\\[2ex]& =\dfrac{1}{2}e^{j\frac{\pi}{6}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{31}e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}k(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{3})}+\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{6}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{31}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}k(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{3})}\end{alignat}$$Seeing as how it resembles the geometric sum, I then got the result: $$S[n]=\dfrac{1}{2}e^{j\frac{\pi}{6}}\dfrac{1-e^{j8\pi}}{1-e^{j\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{3})}}+\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{6}}\dfrac{1-e^{-j8\pi}}{1-e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{3})}}$$where I got stuck. In order to have the power of $e$ from denominator be a multiple of $2\pi$, I need to fulfill the condition $$\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{n}{6}=2$$respectively $$\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{n}{6}=2$$neither of which seem to hold any meaningful results.
My other solution involves using the DFT formula for real and even signals (which $s[k]$ is): $$S[n]=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1}x[k]\cos{\Bigg(\dfrac{2\pi kn}{N}\Bigg)},\quad n=\overline{0,\ N-1}$$
Now when I use this, my DFT becomes: $$S[n] =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{31}\cos{\Bigg(\dfrac{\pi}{4}k+\dfrac{\pi}{6}\Bigg)}\cos{\Bigg(\dfrac{2\pi kn}{N}\Bigg)}$$
If I use the trigonometric relation: $$\cos{(\alpha)}\cos{(\beta)}=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big[\cos{(\alpha-\beta)}+\cos{(\alpha+\beta)}\Big]$$Then my $S[n]$ becomes: $$S[n]=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{31}\dfrac{1}{2}\Bigg[\cos{\Bigg(\dfrac{\pi}{4}k+\dfrac{\pi}{6}-\dfrac{2\pi kn}{32}\Bigg)}+\cos{\Bigg(\dfrac{\pi}{4}k+\dfrac{\pi}{6}+\dfrac{2\pi kn}{32}\Bigg)}\Bigg]$$
But I am once against stuck. Calculating this by hand will take a long time and I don't exactly see how to simplify it. I feel like I am either missing steps, not further simplifying the problem or straight up just solving it wrong.
I realize that this problem is probably way simpler than whatever I am trying to solve, but I also am not sure how to approach it besides my weak attempts that I described above.

I've provided a solution to this problem in this answer.

Thank you for pointing me towards that answer, Matt. With the mathematical explanation provided by you, I was able to fill in some of the blanks I had

Hint: The DFT of a complex sine wave that has an integer number of periods in the DFT window is simply a Kronecker Delta at that frequency. We can write the time domain signal as
$$x[n] = e^{j2\pi\frac{mn}{N}} \tag{1} $$
and it's DFT is then
$$X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j2\pi\frac{mn}{N}} e^{-j2\pi\frac{kn}{N}} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{j2\pi\frac{(m-k(}{N}} = \\
\begin{cases} N & m=k \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Hello! Your hint is actually really helpful, but my problem lies in getting to write the signal under that form, the $e^{j2\pi\frac{mn}{N}}$. When trying to follow the login, I am a bit stuck on how to go from $\cos{\Big(2\pi\frac{F}{F_S} n + \phi\Big)}$ to $\cos{\Big(2\pi\frac{mn}{N}+\phi\Big)}$. I assume we drop the $\phi$ anyway, but I am still a bit lost on the transition from $\frac{F}{F_S}$ to $\frac{m}{N}$. If $F$ considered the 'current' frequency of the sinusoidal, hence the $m$ frequency index out of a total of $N$ such samples?

Yep. That’s it. Let’s assume sampling rate of 3200Hz and a DFT length of 32. Your FFT grid is then 0, 100, 200, 300 Hz etc with the indices being 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively. So $m=2$ would correspond to 200Hz in this case.  We have simply $m = f \cdot N /f_s$ . Note that my hint only works if $m$ comes out to be a whole number, i.e. $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ otherwise it’s a whole different can of worms

Thank you so much for this explanation, now I finally get how to solve these
